# Automating Import to Two Orgs Using Dataloader

Tags: data-loader

We then have a batch file scheduled to run every night to extract data from an external system. We then would like to have the data loader push the data into two separate SalesForce orgs. Is it possible to point one instance of the dataloader to separate orgs using different config files?